# How to use GREATEST function with Over Partition by in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In the below code I want to select customer_name, location, gender and address along with customerid, aread_code.

```
select 
    customerid, aread_code, GREATEST(MAX(productid), MAX(itemid))
from   
    CUSTOMER C 
inner join 
    ORDER O ON c.custid = o.custid
where  
    c.custtype = 'EXECUTIVE'
group 
    customerid, by aread_code;
```

I tried `GREATEST` function along with `OVER PARTITION` BY to display required columns. It's throwing an error.

Could you please help me to select the required columns.

Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with your current query (which looks correct), and why do think you need to use `GREATEST()` as an analytic function here?

Comment: I wan to get MAX(C.productid) OR MAX(O.itemid) which one is highest. Along with that need customer_name,location,gener ,address , customerid and aread_code in the output.

Comment: Your current query looks totally valid to me.

Comment: Could be that we don't quite understand what you want. Please, provide sample data and desired result (based on that sample).

Comment: I wan to get MAX(C.productid) OR MAX(O.itemid) which one is highest for each cusromerid and area_code combination. Along with that need customer_name,location,gener ,address , customerid and aread_code in the output.

Comment: Your use of `greatest` looks OK, but you have the keyword `by` in the wrong place - it should be `group by customerid, aread_code`. Is that the error you were getting? (It would be helpful to give details in your question rather than just saying it's "throwing an error".) If you want more columns from the customer table then just add those to both the select list and group-by clause.

Comment: but you have the keyword by in the wrong place. Sorry that is typo error. If I use all the select columns in the group by getting incorrect result. I wan to get MAX(C.productid) OR MAX(O.itemid) which one is highest for each cusromerid and area_code combination. Along with that need customer_name,location,gener ,address , customerid and aread_code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code. The main confusion is not using table alias prefix for columns. There is a group by mistake and a problem with your table name ORDER - if it is a name of a table. ORDER is a reserved word in Oracle and if it is the name of the table then you should use something like "YOUR_OWNER_NAME"."ORDER".... Here is the corected code with some sample  data and result:

```sql
WITH 
    customers  (CUSTID, PRODUCTID, AREAD_CODE, CUSTOMER_NAME, LOCATION, GENDER, ADDRESS, CUSTTYPE)  AS
        (
            Select 1, 1, 63,  'Name 1', 'Location 1', 'M', 'Address 1', 'EXECUTIVE' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 1, 63,  'Name 1', 'Location 1', 'M', 'Address 1', 'EXECUTIVE' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 3, 63,  'Name 1', 'Location 1', 'M', 'Address 1', 'EXECUTIVE' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 7, 63,  'Name 1', 'Location 1', 'M', 'Address 1', 'EXECUTIVE' From Dual           
        ),
    orders (ORDER_ID, CUSTID, ITEMID, SOME_COLUMN)  AS
        (
            Select 1, 1, 1, 'Some other data' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 2, 1, 'Some other data' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 3, 1, 'Some other data' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 3, 3, 'Some other data' From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 4, 1, 'Some other data' From Dual Union All
            Select 6, 4, 8, 'Some other data' From Dual 
        )

select 
    c.custid, c.aread_code, GREATEST(MAX(c.productid), MAX(o.itemid)) "MAX_ID"
from   
    CUSTOMERS C 
inner join 
    ORDERS O ON c.custid = o.custid
where  
    c.custtype = 'EXECUTIVE'
group by
    c.custid, c.aread_code

    CUSTID AREAD_CODE     MAX_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         63          1 
         4         63          8 
         3         63          3 
         2         63          1
```

There are different options to get the rest of the columns depending on your actual data you could use some or all of them.

Option 1 - select and group by as suggested in Beefstu's comment below

```sql
select Distinct
    c.custid, c.customer_name, c.location, c.address, c.gender, c. custtype, c.aread_code, 
    GREATEST(MAX(c.productid), MAX(o.itemid)) "MAX_ID"
from   
    CUSTOMERS C 
inner join 
    ORDERS O ON c.custid = o.custid
where  
    c.custtype = 'EXECUTIVE'
group by
    c.custid, c.customer_name, c.location, c.address, c.gender, c. custtype, c.aread_code
order  by c.custid


    CUSTID CUSTOMER_NAME LOCATION   ADDRESS   GENDER CUSTTYPE  AREAD_CODE     MAX_ID
---------- ------------- ---------- --------- ------ --------- ---------- ----------
         1 Name 1        Location 1 Address 1 M      EXECUTIVE         63          1 
         2 Name 1        Location 1 Address 1 M      EXECUTIVE         63          1 
         3 Name 1        Location 1 Address 1 M      EXECUTIVE         63          3 
         4 Name 1        Location 1 Address 1 M      EXECUTIVE         63          8
```

Option 2. - using analytic functions MAX() OVER() with Distinct keyword (could be performance costly with big datasets) - result is the same as above

```sql
select Distinct
    c.custid, c.customer_name, c.location, c.address, c.gender, c. custtype, c.aread_code, 
    GREATEST(MAX(c.productid) OVER(Partition By c.custid), MAX(o.itemid) OVER(Partition By c.custid)) "MAX_ID"
from   
    CUSTOMERS C 
inner join 
    ORDERS O ON c.custid = o.custid
where  
    c.custtype = 'EXECUTIVE'
order  by c.custid
```

Option 3 - using left join to a subquery - see the solution offered by Thorsten Kettner

Comment: Thanks for your code . I want to display all these columns customer_name,location,gender ,address , customerid and aread_code.But we should group by only  customerid and aread_code.

Comment: Whatever other information you want displayed add to the SELECT and group by statements. The group by order should match the SELECT statement 7

Comment: @Rock - just posted a few options for the rest of the columns...

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:**

When working with more than one table, qualify the columns with their table name. You haven't done so, so we don't know what of the two tables the `aread_code` resides in. In my answer here I assume it is the customer's area. If it isn't then you need a different answer.

**ANSWER:**

You group by customer_id and area code. This gives you one row per customer. And you want the maximum product/item ID from the orders table. (I suppose they are drawn from the same sequence, so you can use this ID somehow to go on from there.)

The easiest approach for this is to get the maximum ID in a subquery. Either directly in the select clause or in the from clause.

Here is how to do this in the `SELECT` clause:

```
select
  c.*,
  (
    select greatest(max(productid), max(itemid))
    from orders o
    where o.custid = c.custid
  ) as max_id
from customer c 
where c.custtype = 'EXECUTIVE';
```

Here is one way to do this in the `FROM` clause:

```
select
  c.*,
  agg.max_id
from customer c 
outer apply
(
  select greatest(max(productid), max(itemid)) as max_id
  from orders o
  where o.custid = c.custid
) agg
where c.custtype = 'EXECUTIVE';
```

And here is another way to do this in the `FROM` clause:

```
select
  c.*,
  agg.max_id
from customer c 
left outer join
(
  select
    custid,
    greatest(max(productid), max(itemid)) as max_id
  from orders
  group by custid
) agg on agg.custid = c.custid
where c.custtype = 'EXECUTIVE';
```

If you only want customers with at least one order, then I recommend the approach with the `FROM` clause. You'd have to turn the `OUTER APPLY` into a `CROSS APPLY` resp. the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` for this.